# Crystal Reports Framework Download

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, installation, report

Can anyone tell me how to download the Framework for Crystal Reports so that it will run on my development server? I have it running locally but when I depoly it, I get the error saying that the framework is not installed. I tried copying the dll's locally to the bin folder but that did not work. Everytime I access the SAP site, it asks me to login. Just wondering if anyone has a link so I can download it. Thanks.

Here is the error I get:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of the Crystal Reports libraries for. Net can be found [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824). For your deployment it might be a good idea to use the provided merge modules (if you are building an MSI installer anyway).